# Catch click event on absolute position element

Tags: javascript

I have div and over it is link with absolute position div. I need to catch click event on link and get "href" attribute. I don't want to use any library only plain JavaScript. Is it possible?

I tried something like this but it catches only div outside of link.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function ()
{
    document.addEventListener('click', $openExternalLink, false);
});


function $openExternalLink(e) {
    alert(e.target.tagName);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>Text</div>
<a href="..."><div style="position: absolute; left: ..., top: ..."></div></a>
```

Maybe this structure is terrible unfortunately I cannot influence it.

Thank you

Comment: The `target` property is the element that was clicked - in your case the `div`. You can use `e.target.parentNode.href` to get the link href or simply attach the click handler to the link and look for `e.currentTarget.href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.onload = function() {
    var myLink = document.querySelector("a");
    myLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var href = this.href;
    })
}
```

Simply add an event listener to your anchor, then get its `href` attribute with `this.href` (or this.getAttribute("href"))

I'll assume you're fairly new to JavaScript? if so, definitely go check out http://CodeCademy.com/

Also, something I just though of, if you want to handle the link with a function (as it seems you do), do something like this instead:

```
document.onload = function() {
    var myLink = document.querySelector("a");
    myLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Makes the event prevent the default link behaviour
        var href = this.href;
        externalLink(href);
    })
}
externalLink(href) {
    // Do something with your link.
    // perhaps, window.location = href (or whatever)
}
```

To use for ALL links on a page (as per your comment), do the following:

```
document.onload = function() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    var i = 0, count = links.length;
    for (i; i < count; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            externalLink(this.href);
        })
    }
}
externalLink(href) {
    // Do something with your link.
    // perhaps, window.location = href (or whatever)
}
```

Used `querySelectorAll` to target ALL anchor tags in the document, and then for-looped through them, adding an event listener to each. Keep in mind, this script needs some tweaking if you also want to support IE8. (using `attachEvent("onclick"...` instead of `addEventListener`, and replacing `this` with `links[i]` within the event)

Comment: Why `this.getAttribute("href")` versus `this.href`?

Comment: Uhh, I'm just used to certain things, but you're right. `this.href` makes just as much sense, and is shorter. I'll swap it out.

Comment: Nice, however, it works only for the first link on page. Is there any simple modification for all links?

Comment: Yup, use `querySelectorAll` and for-loop through them. I will add it to my answer.